# How to write a mysql query in symfony2.0?

Tags: mysql, symfony

I have a mysql query but i do not know how to make a query in symfony2.0.

Query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name,
FROM `ms_musiccategory` a
LEFT OUTER JOIN `ms_musiccategory` b ON a.parent_Id = b.id
ORDER BY coalesce( b.name, a.name ) , a.name
```

Comment: @tombom:please reply not to edited...

Answer (score -2):

```
 $con = $this -> getEntityManager() -> getConnection();

 $st = $con -> prepare(' SELECT a.* FROM `tablename` a LEFT OUTER JOIN `tablename` b ON a.parent_Id = b.id ORDER BY coalesce( b.name, a.name ) , a.name');

 $st -> execute();

 $list = $st -> fetchAll();
```